# array_search() fault

Tags: php, arrays

Array replace doesn't work properly or I'm missing something.

I want to replace any text which is equal to 'An Error Occured while reading' with 'Reading has stopped after fatal error in you XML file but when I use PHP code below the value against key **0** gets updated which is wrong!

Any idea?

Thanks

**Original state:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Element 'item', attribute 'isd': The attribute 'isd' is not allowed.
    [1] => Element 'item', attribute 'avai0lable': The attribute 'avai0lable' is not allowed.
    [2] => Unimplemented block at ..\xmlschemas.c:28274
    [3] => An Error Occured while reading
)
```

**PHP code:**

```
$errors = array_unique($errors);
$key = array_search('An Error Occured while reading', $errors);
$errors[$key] = 'Reading has stopped after fatal error in you XML file';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); echo '</pre>';
```

**Faulty result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Reading has stopped after fatal error in you XML file
    [1] => Element 'item', attribute 'avai0lable': The attribute 'avai0lable' is not allowed.
    [2] => Unimplemented block at ..\xmlschemas.c:28274
    [3] => Reading has stopped after fatal error in you XML file
)
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($key)` give you?

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact code you are using? Because it's working fine or me.

Comment: bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) int(3)

Comment: Adding `if ($key !== false) { replace }` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct code is:**

```
$errors = array_unique($errors);
$key = array_search('An Error Occured while reading', $errors);
if($key)
 $errors[$key] = 'Reading has stopped after fatal error in you XML file';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); echo '</pre>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried below code ,I am not able to reproduce what u saying:

```
<?php
$errors = Array
( "Element 'item', attribute 'isd': The attribute 'isd' is not allowed.",
    "Element 'item', attribute 'avai0lable': The attribute 'avai0lable' is not allowed.",
    'Unimplemented block at ..\xmlschemas.c:28274',
    'An Error Occured while reading',
);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); echo '</pre>';
$errors = array_unique($errors);
$key = array_search('An Error Occured while reading', $errors);
$errors[$key] = 'Reading has stopped after fatal error in you XML file';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Script:

```
<?php

$data = array (
    0 => "Element 'item', attribute 'isd': The attribute 'isd' is not allowed.",
    1 => "Element 'item', attribute 'avai0lable': The attribute 'avai0lable' is not allowed.",
    2 => "Unimplemented block at ..\xmlschemas.c:28274",
    3 => "An Error Occured while reading"
);

$new_data = array();
$a = "An Error Occured while reading";
$b = "Reading has stopped after fatal error in you XML file";

foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
    $new_data[$key] = str_replace( $a, $b, $value );
}

?>
```

Output of `$new_data`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Element 'item', attribute 'isd': The attribute 'isd' is not allowed.
    [1] => Element 'item', attribute 'avai0lable': The attribute 'avai0lable' is not allowed.
    [2] => Unimplemented block at ..\xmlschemas.c:28274
    [3] => Reading has stopped after fatal error in you XML file
)
```